# Can't install Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: boot, server

I want to install ubuntu 20.04 server but it's throw an Error `ACPI BIOS ERROR: Failure creating named object[\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.SS10.PLD], AE_ALDEADY_EXISTS`
I also tried **acpi=off,nopaic,nolapic,nomodeset**

I also tried UEFI, legacy modes too.
Some more Errors
`RIP:0010:0x0, Code:Bad RIP value` 
and one more
 `Kernel panic- not syncing:Fatal exception`

Comment: what is the machine you are trying to install it on ?

Comment: Is this a dual boot or a new install? Do you have more information so we might be of help?

Comment: It is a  lenova and yes it's a new install

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It have an error on diskpart system(you can not delete when while installing it is not appear ),try to install other linux distribution and remove that diskpart from it(harddisk).